Can no longer access switch interface once VLANs are in play
I'm running an AX23 router with OpenWrt which gets the WAN connection from my ISP gateway in Bridge mode, and I've connected to its LAN port 1 a Netgear GS108Tv3 Smart Managed switch (to its own port 8). Here's how I have it configured:
Router (OpenWrt)
Bridge 1 (br-lan):

device has LAN ports 1 & 2 attached; VLANs 10 & 20 are filtered with LAN port 1 being the trunk for both VLANs and LAN port 2 is set as untagged and PVID for VLAN 10, and not part of VLAN 20
two interfaces, one for each VLAN; VLAN 10 has a DHCP server for the 192.168.10.x range and VLAN 20 has a DHCP server for the 192.168.20.x range
both interfaces are in the lan firewall zone

Bridge 2 (br-lan2):

device has LAN ports 3 & 4 attached; no VLAN filtering
one interface; a DHCP server for the 192.168.0.x range
the interfaces is also in the lan firewall zone

Switch (GS108Tv3)

IP address is 192.168.0.239/24 with default gateway as 192.168.0.1 (DHCP)
VLAN 1: all ports are untagged members
VLAN 10: port 4 is untagged, port 8 is tagged
VLAN 20: port 2 is untagged, port 8 is tagged
PVID 10 is assigned to port 4, PVID 20 is assigned to port 2

With this configuration, if I plug a PC into port 4 of the switch I get an Internet connection and I'm able to access the router's interface via IP address 192.168.0.1 & 192.168.10.1, but I am unable to access the switch's own interface via IP address 192.168.0.239. However, if I plug the switch into port 3 of the router instead of 1 and connect a PC directly into the port 2 of the router, I'm able to configure the switch as before. What part of my configuration is wrong?
I know this is a lot of detail but I am new to networking so I would really appreciate any help you can give!


With this configuration, if I plug a PC into port 4 of the switch I get an Internet connection and I'm able to access the router's interface via IP address 192.168.0.1 & 192.168.10.1, but I am unable to access the switch's own interface via IP address 192.168.0.239.
However, if I plug the switch into port 3 of the router instead of 1 and connect a PC directly into the port 2 of the router, I'm able to configure the switch as before.

Port 1 is not on the 192.168.0.0/24 network – that network is configured on the br-lan2 interface, which port 1 is not a member of. When the router needs to forward a packet to 192.168.0.239, it will get routed via br-lan2 and will only exit through ports 3/4.
The effect of having two separate bridges is literally that the untagged VLAN1 of br-lan is completely isolated from the untagged VLAN1 of br-lan2 (and the same goes for all other VLANs and everything else).  So if you want 192.168.0.x to be available on the router's all ports, then they should all be part of a single bridge.
(You're still able to access the router's own 192.168.0.1 address because the router knows that this is its own local address, no matter which interface it's on – doesn't need to ARP for it, or to send any packets anywhere – but you wouldn't be able to access any other 192.168.0.x address if it were connected to ports 1 or 2; there is nothing special about the Netgear here.)
In fact, since you're running OpenWRT on a device that has an integrated switch chip, and presumably you want to use its fast hardware-level packet switching (as opposed to bridging through the potato CPU), I believe having a single bridge is the only way to do things – often the switch chip does not have the capability to isolate groups of ports in any other way except through VLANs, so having two bridges is likely to prevent them both from being hardware-accelerated (as that would lose isolation between bridges).
[Though routing between VLANs still has to go through the CPU, of course.]
So my suggestion is to use a single bridge with VLAN filtering, configuring its VLANs and PVIDs exactly as you would configure them on the Netgear switch.

Yes, this was it. The bridge that was running the 192.168.0.x interface was separate from the other VLANs. Thanks!
